# Split xml file with result document and javax.xml.transform.Transformer

Tags: xslt

I have a XSLT which will split large xml file into multiple xml file with the use of following xslt code.

```
<xsl:variable name="filename" select="resolve-uri(concat('splitfilesfolder/',position(),'.xml'))" /> 
 <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="xml">
    <--XML file content --->
 </xsl:result-document>
```

then i have used that XSLT in my code to split input XML file using javax.xml.transform.Transformer.

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Source xslSource =  new StreamSource(xsltfilepath);

Transformer trans = tFactory.newTransformer(xslSource);
trans.transform(new StreamSource(xmlFileName), new StreamResult(splitfilesfolder));
```

Here i want to give same path for new Streamresult as it is in result document path how can i transform multiple xml file using result doucment and javax.xml.transform.Transform ??

Can anybody please give me a solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<xsl:result-document>` is in XSLT 2.0 javax.xml.transform does not support XSLT 2.0, so i'm under the impression that you're out of luck using built-in transformers.

Try using [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/) instead. Just add the jar file to your classpath and you're set.

There is also an error in your XSLT

```
 <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="xml">
```

Should be

```
 <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" method="xml">
```

To get the directory into your XSLT i'd use

Java

```
trans.setParameter("dir", "dirname");
```

XSL

```
<xsl:param name="dir"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter , I have resolved my problem what you have suggested.
I have used Saxon for the result document and split the file .

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of Saxon's TransformerFactory directly, i.e.
    TransformerFactoryImpl factory = new TransformerFactoryImpl();
Do not use the brain-dead JAXP
    TransformerFactory.newInstance();
...as you're clearly getting something other than Saxon's implmentation.

Comment: Since Java 1.6, you can make sure you get the implementation you want using `TransformerFactory.newInstance("net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl", null)`, for example.